# How to change dropdown box background along with arrow in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, dropdownbox

I need to change the background of the drop down box

```
<select>
   <option value="Chrome">Google Chrome</option>
   <option value="Fire Fox">Fire Fox</option>
   <option value="Opera">Opera</option>
  </select>
```

1)Below is the CSS
2)i can give background but it will be display like below link http://jsfiddle.net/vamsivelaga/9bt5vncg/

```
select{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 26px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    text-overflow: '';
    background: url(http://s24.postimg.org/lyhytocf5/dropdown.png) no-repeat right 0;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;}
```

Comment: You have already set a background image, do you want to change it or do you want to get rid of the image?

Comment: just a quick reminder that this won't work in FF 30 and above, The -moz-appearence doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the background, just add some color at the end of "background".

For example 
.drop_down_style{
background: url(http://s24.postimg.org/lyhytocf5/dropdown.png) no-repeat right #000;
}

The above code adds black color and replaces the default image with the url which is provided.

You can refer to this [link](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)  if needed.

Comment: Thq Baradwaj Aryasomaya it is working in Chrome but it is not working in Mozilla, please re-solve the probelem.

Comment: If you are referring to the background color change... it is working in both the browsers. I posted here after testing it. The following is the code I am using and it is working fine.                                           .drop_text {
 margin-top:5px;
 width: 240px;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(new_arrow.png) no-repeat right black;
    border: 1px #d4d4d4;
}